# Controlling volume in Sonic Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to code a polyphonic song in Sonic Pi, and I really need to be able to control the volume. I've looked through the Sonic Pi tutorials and found nothing. Please help.

Specifically, I've tried using [play :A4, amp: 3.0] and fiddling with the amplitude, but for some reason it doesn't work. Below is a code snippet of a sequence of two-note chords:

```
play :E3, release: 0.5, amp: 3.0
play :A4, release: 0.5, amp: 3.0
sleep 0.2
play :E3, release: 0.5, amp: 1.0
play :E3, release: 0.5, amp: 1.0
sleep 0.2
play :D3, release: 0.25, amp: 2.0
play :E3, release: 0.25, amp: 2.0
sleep 0.2
play :Fs3, release: 0.5
play :Gs4, release: 0.5
```

but the volume just isn't changing. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think that it might be because you are using numbers with decimals, and you might have to use 3 and not 3.0, 2 and not 2.0, and etc. If not, I don't honestly know why it isn't working.